# VIdeoJs - Play button doesn't display properly in SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, video.js

This bothers me for a few days, and I couldn't get it solved. Please if you have seen this before, kindly let me know what the issue is. Thanks.

I have included the following two lines to the SharePoint 2013 master page:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.11.7/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.11.7/video.js"></script>
```

Here is the HTML code generated from a SharePoint API call (it is a webpart):

```
<video id='my-video' class='video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered' controls preload='none' data-setup='{}'>
<source src='test.flv' type='video/x-flv'/>
<p class='vjs-no-js'>To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that<a href='http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/' target='_blank'>supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

Result in IE 11 and Chrome 53.0.2785.143. Click on the square button, it plays the FLV file perfectly, just the initial play button and buttons on the control are displaying incorrectly.

> Play Button doesn't display correctly:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSY8R.png
>
> Button on the control doesn't display correctly:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvK3g.png

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the question myself:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.7/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.7/video.js"></script>
```

Version 4.7 seems to be working fine in SharePoint 2013